# How to get the objectives from an array

Tags: javascript

**The JSON data I am working on it. This is coming from facebook ad api.this is being build for google data studio connector**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "campaign_name": "Daily Shopping - [Reach Ad]",
      "cpm": "0.080487",
      "spend": "447.16",
      "actions": [
        {
          "action_type": "post",
          "value": "25"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "video_view",
          "value": "485128"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "link_click",
          "value": "1392"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "photo_view",
          "value": "1014"
        }]},
        {
      "campaign_name": "SERT - [Reach Ad]",
      "cpm": "0.080487",
      "spend": "447.16",
      "actions": [
        {
          "action_type": "post",
          "value": "25"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "video_view",
          "value": "485128"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "comment",
          "value": "1392"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "photo_view",
          "value": "1014"
         }]}
```

Here is the JavaScript code I have used in google app script but it is wrong.

```
result = arr.reduce((r,o) => {r[o.action_type] = o.value; return r; }, {});
```

**Output should be like the following way so that i can get actions in objective **

```
"data": [
      {
         "campaign_name": "Daily Shopping - [Reach Ad]",
         "cpm": "0.080487",
         "spend": "447.16",
         "post":"25",
         "video_view":"485128",
         "comment":"1392",
         "photo_view":"1014"
       },
          {
         "campaign_name": SERT - [Reach Ad]",
         "cpm": "0.080487",
         "spend": "447.16",
         "post":"25",
         "video_view":"485128",
         "link_click":"1392",
         "photo_view":"1014"
       },
```

Comment: After your update, it makes no more sense that in your attempt you do `arr.reduce`. If `arr` refers to that structure above, then it is not an array. It would be good show your code in one piece, where the data structure is available as a *variable*, and where your code works with *that* variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
    "campaign_name": "Daily Shopping - [Reach Ad]",
    "cpm": "0.080487",
    "spend": "447.16",
    "actions": [{
        "action_type": "post",
        "value": "25"
      },
      {
        "action_type": "video_view",
        "value": "485128"
      },
      {
        "action_type": "link_click",
        "value": "1392"
      },
      {
        "action_type": "photo_view",
        "value": "1014"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "campaign_name": "SERT - [Reach Ad]",
    "cpm": "0.080487",
    "spend": "447.16",
    "actions": [{
        "action_type": "post",
        "value": "25"
      },
      {
        "action_type": "video_view",
        "value": "485128"
      },
      {
        "action_type": "comment",
        "value": "1392"
      },
      {
        "action_type": "photo_view",
        "value": "1014"
      }
    ]
  }
];
dataN = data.map(d => {
  return {
    campaign_name: d.campaign_name,
    cpm: d.cpm,
    spend: d.spend,
    post: d.actions[0].value,
    video_view: d.actions[1].value,
    comment: d.actions[2].value,
    photo_view: d.actions[3].value,

  }
})
console.log(dataN);
```

Comment: That worked but i can not fix the code. I have edited the question. Could you please help me?

Comment: I have updated answer to fit with you json

Comment: I would suggest @trincot answer is much more future proof.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with `Object.fromEntries` and spread syntax in object literals:

```js
let response = {"data": [{"campaign_name": "Daily Shopping - [Reach Ad]","cpm": "0.080487","spend": "447.16","actions": [{"action_type": "post","value": "25"},{"action_type": "video_view","value": "485128"},{"action_type": "link_click","value": "1392"},{"action_type": "photo_view","value": "1014"}]}, {"campaign_name": "SERT - [Reach Ad]","cpm": "0.080487","spend": "447.16","actions": [{"action_type": "post","value": "25"},{"action_type": "video_view","value": "485128"},{"action_type": "comment","value": "1392"},{"action_type": "photo_view","value": "1014"}]}]};
         
const result = {
    data: response.data.map(({actions, ...rest}) => ({
        ...rest,
        ...Object.fromEntries(actions.map(({action_type, value}) => 
            [action_type, value]
        ))
    }))
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That worked but i can not fix the code. I have edited the question. Could you please help me?

Comment: I updated the answer to match your updated question. You didn't give the name of your response, so I assumed you have it in a variable called `response`. Adapt as needed.

Comment: When I use this code in data studio, it is showing an error " Missing : after property ID "

Comment: Well, you can see it runs here without issue, so I guess you're using some older JavaScript version. In that case it would be helpful if you would list such a restriction (ECMA Script version) in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much. After changing the version, It is working now.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72938823/how-to-structure-and-all-data-in-the-objective-from-json-at-app-script)
Can you please help me on this issue?

Comment: I see you are using there the code that I posted in my answer here. Since you accepted another answer, why did you go with my code?

Comment: I have lack of knowledge on Javascript. Thats y I have used there

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. As you can see, only the initial argument passed to the reducer needs to be modified. The modification can be applied in situ.

**Code**

```js
 let s_x = `{
      "data": [
          {
             "campaign_name": "Daily Shopping - [Reach Ad]",
             "reach": "2365439",
             "clicks": "43692",
             "impressions": "4873908",
             "actions": [
                {
                   "action_type": "like",
                   "value": "1"
                },
                {
                   "action_type": "comment",
                   "value": "40"
                 }
             ],
             "date_start": "2022-05-27",
             "date_stop": "2022-06-03"
          }
        ]
       }`
   , x = JSON.parse(s_x)
   ;


x.data.forEach ( po_orig => {
    let o_transformed = po_orig.actions.reduce ((r,o) => {
            r[o.action_type] = o.value; return r;
        }, po_orig) // Note: po_orig instead of {}
      ;

    delete po_orig['actions'];
}); 

console.log(`new data: `, x);
```

Comment: That worked but i can not fix the code. I have edited the question. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an implementation using `Object.entries()` and `reduce()`

```
const raw_data = `{
  "data": [
      {
         "campaign_name": "Daily Shopping - [Reach Ad]",
         "reach": "2365439",
         "clicks": "43692",
         "impressions": "4873908",
         "actions": [
            {
               "action_type": "like",
               "value": "1"
            },
            {
               "action_type": "comment",
               "value": "40"
             }
         ],
         "date_start": "2022-05-27",
         "date_stop": "2022-06-03"
      }
    ]
   }`;

const data = JSON.parse(raw_data).data;

const processedData = Object.entries(data[0]).reduce(
  (accumulator, [currentProperty, currentValue]) => {
    if (currentProperty !== "actions") {
      if (!currentProperty.includes("date"))
        accumulator[currentProperty] = currentValue;
    } else {
      currentValue.forEach(
        (action) => (accumulator[action.action_type] = action.value)
      );
    }
    return accumulator;
  },
  {}
);

console.log(processedData);
```

Comment: That worked but i can not fix the code. I have edited the question. Could you please help me?

Comment: I think @trincot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72776706/19365920) works well in that case. If it does work, you should probably set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the simple Object assign without removing the existing format of data to get the result you want.

```js
const arr = [{"campaign_name": "Daily Shopping - [Reach Ad]","reach": "2365439","clicks": "43692","impressions": "4873908","actions": [{"action_type": "like","value": "1"},{"action_type": "comment","value": "40"}],"date_start": "2022-05-27","date_stop": "2022-06-03"}];

let result = arr.reduce((a, r,o) => {
    Object.assign({}, r['actions'].reduce((d,e,f) => {
        
        r[e['action_type']] = e['value'];    
        
    }, {}), r);

    
    return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```