# How to structure and all data in the objective from Json at App script

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, looker-studio

**The JSON data I am working on it. This is coming from Facebook ad API. This is being build for google data studio connector**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "adcreatives": {
        "data": [
          {
            "actor_id": "8834759718540",
            "id": "538"
          }
        ]
      },
      "insights": {
        "data": [
          {
            "ad_id": "34536578578",
            "impressions": "89108",
            "actions": [
              {
                "action_type": "comment",
                "value": "02"
              },
              {
                "action_type": "post",
                "value": "03"
              }
            ],
            "date_start": "2022-06-11",
            "date_stop": "2022-07-10"
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "before": "MAZDZD",
            "after": "MAZDZD"
          }
        }
      },
    "created_time": "2022-06-10T22:59:33+0600",
      "id": "34536578578"
    },
    {
      "adcreatives": {
        "data": [
          {
            "actor_id": "7834759718970",
            "id": "342"
          }
        ]
      },
      "insights": {
        "data": [
          {
            "ad_id": "238509545896206",
            "impressions": "57803",
            "actions": [
              {
                "action_type": "post_engagement",
                "value": "2102"
              },
              {
                "action_type": "page_engagement",
                "value": "03"
              }
            ],
            "date_start": "2022-06-11",
            "date_stop": "2022-07-10"
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "before": "MAZDZD",
            "after": "MAZDZD"
          }
        }
      },
      "created_time": "2022-06-11T22:59:33+0600",
      "id": "238509545896206"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "dfgdfgdfgdfsdgdfgdfgdfgdfgdgdg",
      "after": "yuyuyuyutyuytuyutytynfrgersggsgs"
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is the JavaScript code I have used in google app script but it is showing error. I know it is totally wrong**

```
var data = {data: parseData.data.map(({actions, ...rest}) => ({...rest,...Object.fromEntries(actions.map(({action_type, value}) =>[action_type, value]))}))};
console.log(data);
```

**Output should be like the following way so that I can get all the data in objective**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "actor_id": "8834759718540",
      "id": "538",
      "ad_id": "34536578578",
      "impressions": "89108",
      "comment": "02",
      "post": "03",
      "date_start": "2022-06-11",
      "date_stop": "2022-07-10",
      "created_time": "2022-06-10T22:59:33+0600"
    },
    {
      "actor_id": "7834759718970",
      "id": "342",
      "ad_id": "238512373324806",
      "impressions": "57803",
      "post_engagement": "2102",
      "page_engagement": "03",
      "date_start": "2022-06-11",
      "date_stop": "2022-07-10"
      "created_time": "2022-06-11T22:59:33+0600"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MAZDZD",
      "after": "MQZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if `adcreatives` has more than one actor in its `data` array, and also `insights` has more than one entry in its `data` array? NB: the code you used from my previous answer is about a different data structure: you never reference `adcreatives` or `insights`... So why not do that first?

Comment: There is something weird with the expected output. Data's element looks to come from the data property from your initial object but paging value is filled with insights's paging value instead of initial object pading value, is it a mistake ? Else, it means the final result as 2 property, data and paging where data is an array of element and paging is one property of the first element of the data's array ???

Comment: @trincot that time I was unable to get adcreatives level data. Yes! by your helping your previous code, campaign level data is working now in the app script. 

Now I am working on adcreatives level data. It would be very helpful if you help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below, but it only works if `adcreatives.data` and `insights.data` have only 1 element :

```
let part = data.data.map(item => ({
    "actor_id": item.adcreatives.data.at(0).actor_id,
    "id": item.adcreatives.data.at(0).id,
    "ad_id": item.insights.data.at(0).ad_id,
    "impressions": item.insights.data.at(0).impressions,
    "comment": item.insights.data.at(0).actions.at(0).value,
    "post": item.insights.data.at(0).actions.at(1).value,
    "date_start": item.insights.data.at(0).date_start,
    "date_stop": item.insights.data.at(0).date_stop,
    "created_time": item.created_time
}));

let result = {
    data: part,
    paging: data.paging
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: adcreatives.data have multiple elements with insights.data

Comment: do `adcreatives.data` and `insights.data` both have the same length ?

Comment: No. Different lengths.